# Expandable List View : Single child selection

Tags: android, expandablelistview

There are multiple groups in Expandable list view. I need to select one in each, i.e only one selection from a group. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I did not understand right, but you want to have a selection in each group from the ExpandableListView.

For example, you have 2 groups: Cats, Dogs and you want to select 1 cat, but also 1 dog.

In that case, you need to first set multiple choice on the ListView:

```
ExpandableListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Then, when you want to select any child, use this code in OnChildClickListener.onChildClick():

```
if (groupPosition == 0) // for cats group
{
     parent.setItemChecked(mCheckedCatPosition, false);
     mCheckedCatPosition = childPosition + 1; // + cats header 
     parent.setItemChecked(mCheckedCatPosition, true);
}
else if (groupPosition == 1) // for dogs group
{
     parent.setItemChecked(mCheckedDogPosition, false);
     mCheckedDogPosition = childPosition + 2 + adapter.getChildrenCount(0); // + cats header + dogs header + number of cats
     parent.setItemChecked(mCheckedDogPosition, true);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

on you xml define `listview` and on another xml define `listview_item` which contains a `radio group`, and then on your java activity define `adapter` that takes the radio groubs values for each listview_item (listview_row)

working on expanded list very similar to listview

Comment: Is there any way to do this using BaseExpandableListAdapter?

Comment: yes , just create a class and extend it from `BaseExpandableListAdapter` and write your code for every group on `getChildView` and `getChild`